# How do I get a custom value by ID in Sitefinity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I have added custom fields to the news item component in Sitefinity. I am using `newsItem.GetValue(customFieldName)` to get the value of the field name; however, this is proving to be an issue with translated pages. Is there a way that I can get this value via ID instead? Or how else cna I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a field that can be translated, then you should use the **GetString** method instead of GetValue.

Also check this: 
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/multilingual-getstring-method-does-not-fallback-for-text-field-values